# Can i program in both symfony1 and symfony2 in one application

Tags: php, symfony

I don't know anything about symfony1 but I have just developed a massive web application in symfony2. So I like symfony2 very much. There are many projects in company which are in symfony 1.4.

Now I don't want to go back to learn symfony1.4. But I have to if I have no other option.
I want to know that if I need to add extra features on existing wesite in symfony1.4.

Can I use symfony2 to make those extra features and leave old components in symfony1. Can I work together in symfony1 and symfony1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The two frameworks are utterly different and incompatible. s2 was re-conceived and rebuilt from the ground up. The best you're going to be able to do is communicate between projects via a web services API or something comparable.

s1.4 is very mature and very well-documented (officially and unofficially), so unless your functionality is very customized, you probably will not have much trouble jumping on board s1.4.

Answer (score 0):

**I would say that you can use the SF2 components within SF1.**

But trying to mix both when developing the remaining modules of your app is definitely not what you should even try do do (besides just using some components).

If you're using **Doctrine**, the way you develop your **domain model** will remain the same. So, it's easy to create the controllers/actions and templates in SF1 and use the same domain model of a SF2 application.

So, code it with SF1 and be happy, it will not take too much if you already know the SF philosophy.

Comment: WRT Doctrine, that assumes that the s1.4 stuff uses Doctrine2, which I would think is not the case. s1.4 uses D1.2, or Propel, unless they specifically built it with the D2 plugin.